# How do you define functions that take two object types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I've came across this problem enough times that I figure it's time to ask:

How do you define functions that take two object types in Typescript?

I've also read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html, and understand that the existing union `|` doesn't really work well for objects as it will only contain elements both objects have.

**A Contrived Example**

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type Pet = {
  owner: string;
};

/*
 * We'd like this function to be able to take two different objects as args
 */
const randomFunction = (myObject: Person | Pet) => {
  // PROBLEM:
  // Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Person | Pet'.
  if (typeof myObject.age !== 'undefined') console.log(myObject.age);
};
```

Problem: Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Person | Pet'.

So how do you deal with this? I'd like to be able to pass in two different object types for a simple function.

Is what I'm trying to do not "TypeScripty" or not recommended?

To get rid of the TypeScript squigglies, it seems I'd need to split it out into a different function.

Thanks!

Comment: There is something called `type guards`. [Read more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: In Problem 2 you're trying to pass the _type_, not a value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks can update

Comment: In fact you have quite a few syntactic and semantic errors before we get to what you're actually trying to ask about - make sure what you're posting is actually a [mre]. Check it in e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play.

Comment: In general, with unions, you want [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html). The error inside the function is correct - `isPerson`, despite your intent in naming it, has absolutely no connection to the type of `myObject`, so it's *not* safe to access `age`.

Comment: It's **not** reproducible. The compiler _does_ have an error on the last two lines, but it's _"An argument for 'isPerson' was not provided."_ not _"Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person | Pet'"_ (which you wouldn't get unless you had multiple incompatible types named Person). Check it in the playground (then include that link in your question too).

Comment: Now there isn't an error: https://tsplay.dev/wR5b5W. Note also that taking `isPerson` as a second argument is a bad API (which is presumably why you can't have a parameter that's a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)), because there wouldn't be anything stopping a call `randomFunction(instancePet, true)`, which isn't safe.

Comment: _(Actually you could make `randomFunction(instancePet, true)` invalid with `<T extends Person | Pet>(myObject: T, isPerson: T extends Person ? true : false)`, but 1. that's a bit of an eyesore and 2. `isPerson` still wouldn't be a type predicate inside the function.)_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242043/discussion-between-njho-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: You **do not** have problem 2. _"Argument of type 'Pet' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person | Pet'"_ is _clearly_ wrong ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129908/how-do-you-define-functions-that-take-two-object-types-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment125736484_71129908) unless you have multiple, incompatible types named Pet). And note _"Some random functionality"_ is **not** minimal: https://tsplay.dev/wX7L1W. Read the docs page I linked above, it covers various narrowing options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution is to use a **TypeGuard** as per @Idruskis.

The solution is largely written out here:
https://medium.com/ovrsea/checking-the-type-of-an-object-in-typescript-the-type-guards-24d98d9119b0

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

type Pet = {
  owner: string;
};

// Typeguard
function isPerson(
  data: Pet | Person,
): data is Person {
  if ((data as Person).age) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

const randomFunction = (myObject: Person | Pet) => {
  if (!isPerson(myObject)) return;

  // No error!
  if (typeof myObject.age !== 'undefined') console.log(myObject.age);
};
```